# Upgrading AngularFire causes scripts to stop working?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

The following script is a simple read from firebase using angularfire, firebase, and angular. The issue is that when I upgrade AngularFire from 0.7.1 to .0.8.0 the script completely stops working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

```
<body>
<section ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
         <h3 ng-cloak>{{item.title}}</h3>
    </div>
</section>
<script>

angular.module("myapp", ["firebase"])


.factory("FirebaseService", ["$firebase", function ($firebase) {
    var furl = "https://helloworldtest.firebaseio.com/";
    var ref = new Firebase(furl);
    return $firebase(ref);
    }])

.controller('MyController', ["$scope", "FirebaseService", function ($scope, firebaseservice) {

    $scope.data = firebaseservice

}]);
```

Wit this configuraiton it works fine:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.6/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.min.js'></script>
```

but with this, it doesn't work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.17/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Perhaps it's better not to upgrade.

- See working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisguzman/z8Lpj63w/
- See not working JSFiddle (with angularfire upgrade): http://jsfiddle.net/chrisguzman/z8Lpj63w/

Comment: You're pointing to the same (working) Fiddle twice. But either way, the solution is indeed as @PSL answered: explicitly convert your Firebase ref with `.$asArray()`.

Comment: You upgraded without reading the change log, docs, or release notes. In the future, you may want to make that a discipline. "`NOTE: this release introduces several breaking changes as we work towards a stable 1.0.0 release.`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller do:-

```
 $scope.data = firebaseservice.$asArray(); //or .$asObject
```

Or do it in your service:-

```
 return $firebase(ref).$asObject(); //or .$asObject
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d6rnq4b0/)**

I have never used Firebase but seems like this is a breaking change introduced to improve the functionality, [Found it here](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-30-introducing-angularfire-08.html)

> In previous versions, Firebase data loaded when the AngularFire binding initialized. The improved API provides two methods that load data in different formats. Those methods are $asObject() and $asArray().

Update based on comment from [Kato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/394010/kato)

Here is the [change log](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/changelog.html) stating the changes in the new version. It states the introduction of many breaking changes, so i guess you can expect the same until 1.0 stable release is done. Here is the [official api documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html).

Comment: Also in the [changelog](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/changelog.html) and detailed in the [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular)

Comment: @Kato Thank you!! Actually i have never use Firebase... So posted from  a link where i found some details.. I will update my answer... Links are really helpfule