# firebase: angularfire 0.8.0 upgrade save ref.name in record

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I worked with angularfire 0.6.0 and upgraded to 0.8.0
Befor I saved the firebase record Id into the record like this:

```
  $scope.getOpenPosten.$add({
               uID: "bla"
                }).then(function(ref) {
                    $scope.RecordID = ref.name();
                    $scope.getOpenPosten[id].oID = id;
                    $scope.getOpenPosten.$save(id);
                });
```

but with 0.8.0 I get the error:
     TypeError: Cannot set property 'oID' of undefined

Somebody an idea?

Comment: Probably you may want to use `$asObject()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416654/upgrading-angularfire-causes-scripts-to-stop-working/25416926#25416926

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a large upgrade from 0.6 to 0.8. [Check out the docs for more details](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html).

In 0.6 data was immediately synced when the `$firebase(ref)` binding was called. Now in 0.8 the data won't be synced until either the `$asObject()` or `$asArray()` methods are called.

You can call `$set()`, `$update()`, or `$push()` on the `$firebase(ref)` binding to save data to your Firebase, without syncing any data. If you want to sync and display the data you'll need to call either `$asObject()` or `$asArray()` like mentioned above.

In your case it looks like you want add to a list of items. In this case, `$asArray()` will work best:

```
$scope.openPostens = $firebase(yourRef).$asArray();
$scope.openPostens.$add({ uid: 'blah' }).then(function(ref) {
   ref.update({ oID: ref.name() });
});
```

Also, it looks like you want to save the unique id created by push to the object. In AngularFire you don't necessarily have to do that. [You can call `$id` on any synced `$FirebaseObject` and it will return it's key](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-id).

```
var obj = $firebase(ref).$asObject();
obj.foo = "bar";
obj.$save().then(function(ref) {
   ref.name() === obj.$id; // true
});
```